# Which index(es) should be used in these queries?

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, group-by, having

I have a question about SQL indexing in my theory class. It asks me to choose which column should be indexed to optimize these 2 queries: (This is 'paper' question so I am not provided the database to test these indexes with EXPLAIN)

1, First query.

```
SELECT BranchName, No_Of_Copies 
FROM BOOK as B, BOOK_COPIES as BC, LIBRARY_BRANCH as LB
WHERE B.BookId = BC.BookId and BC.BranchId=LB.BranchId and title ="The Lost Tribe";
```

I have the answer of this one, which is that BOOK.title, BOOK_COPIES.BranchId and LIBRARY_BRANCH.BranchId should be used for indexing. However, I don't really understand why BOOK.BookId and BOOK_COPIES.BookId are not chosen for indexing.

2, Second query

```
SELECT B.cardNo, Name, Address, COUNT(BookId,BranchId) 
FROM BORROWER as B, BOOK_LOANS as BL
WHERE (BL.CardNo=B.CardNo)
GROUP BY B.CardNo, Name, Address
HAVING COUNT(BL.BookId, BranchId)>5;
```

Would it be optimized if I create index on BOOK_LOANS.CardNo, BORROWER.CardNo, Name and Address ?

Comment: "This is 'paper' question so I am not provided the database to test these indexes" -- The paper won't stop you from creating a test database by *yourself*...

Comment: Incidentally, since 1992, your first query would normally be written this way: `SELECT lb.branchname, bc.no_of_copies FROM book b JOIN book_copies bc ON bc.bookid = b.bookid JOIN library_branch lb ON lb.branchid = bc.branchid WHERE title = "the lost tribe";`

Comment: And what does `COUNT(BookId,BranchId)` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That class needs to be updated.  Using commas in `JOIN` is antiquated; the new  style uses `JOIN .. ON`

The question is ambiguous -- what table contains `title`?  I'll assume it is `B`.

1. Since the only filtering is on `title`, The Optimizer will pick `B` as the first table to look at:

   ```
    B needs INDEX(title)
   ```
2. From B, it can reach for BC:

   ```
    BC needs INDEX(BookId)
   ```
3. Similarly:

   ```
    LB needs INDEX(BranchId)
   ```

If you are using MySQL, be aware that a `PRIMARY KEY` is an index.  And every table needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.  Also a `PRIMARY KEY` is necessarily unique.  So, when I said "needs", you may find that there is already a `PRIMARY KEY` satisfying the need.

More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

I will quibble with the schema -- why is the "number of books" not simply a column in `Books`?

As for query 2, it is even less clear which table each column might be in.

Do be aware that an `INDEX` can contain only columns from a single table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Yeah I agree with you that these 2 queries are really ambiguous, but those were exactly what I am provided from my teacher. I asked her for the schema of the database or at least some information about the tables, but she said that I would not need that to do the questions.  However, your explaination on the first query made it clear to me about the answer. As I understand, you mean that `BOOK.BookId` and `BOOK_COPIES.BookId` are primary keys, so they are already indexed and don't need to be included in the answer.